# Unable to resolve Glassfish error

Tags: glassfish, oracle-adf

I have adf application developed using Jdeveloper 12.2.1.2 and i am deploying application on Glassfish server Open Source Edition 5.0.1 (build java_re-private).

Steps I have performed:

1. Compile and create EAR file from Jdeveloper with Glassfish platform.
2. Put adf-essential.zip in Glassfish domain lib folder.
3. Update JVM Option in Glassfish server. Ref [Link](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/deploying-oracle-adf-essentials-applications-to-glassfish)

When i deploy the application i get following error.

```
   Timestamp
Apr 20, 2018 13:13:19.426
Log Level
SEVERE
Logger
oracle.jbo.mom.DefObjectEventManager
Name-Value Pairs
{levelValue=1000, timeMillis=1524210199426}
Record Number
291
Message ID
Complete Message
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: oracle.jbo.mom.DefObjectListener: Provider oracle.jbo.service.helper.SDOSchemaGenListener could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at oracle.jbo.mom.DefObjectEventManager.loadListeners(DefObjectEventManager.java:53)
    at oracle.jbo.mom.DefObjectEventManager.<init>(DefObjectEventManager.java:38)
    at oracle.jbo.mom.DefinitionManager.initListener(DefinitionManager.java:377)
    at oracle.jbo.mom.DefinitionManager.initManager(DefinitionManager.java:399)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.mom.JUMetaObjectManager.initManager(JUMetaObjectManager.java:1475)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.mom.JUMetaObjectManager.<init>(JUMetaObjectManager.java:97)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.mom.JUMetaObjectManager.getJUMom(JUMetaObjectManager.java:369)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.FacesDatabindingConfigurator._installFacesBindingDefFactory(FacesDatabindingConfigurator.java:286)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.FacesDatabindingConfigurator._setupAdfDatabindingForJsf(FacesDatabindingConfigurator.java:136)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.FacesDatabindingConfigurator.init(FacesDatabindingConfigurator.java:48)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl.init(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:469)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.init(RegistrationFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.init(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.init(TrinidadFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4982)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:918)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:685)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1690)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:536)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:276)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:377)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: commonj/sdo/helper/HelperContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 98 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: commonj.sdo.helper.HelperContext
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:865)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:742)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 103 more
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching for `commonj.sdo.helper.HelperContext`, it looks like you are missing ADF classes in your application.

Adding a Zip file to the lib directory won't help, you need to extract it and make sure you add the JAR files. (note that, in the link you specified, it tells you to extract the zip file in step 4).

The better way to add libraries like this to GlassFish is to use the asadmin command like so:

```
./asadmin add-library /path/to/my/library.jar
```

It may be that there are very many JAR files in the zip archive, so the instructions in your link just gave you the quickest solution.